# My Account display only after login

Tags: magento

I would like to change top links
in the default set magento display

My Account | My Wishlist | My Cart | Checkout | Log in

i need to change top link that to show My Account link only after when user is LogIn

thx for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in customer.xml at your theme before it is look like

```
 <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Remove my account link from `default` tag to `Customer_logged_in`
Change it with

**After change at customer.xml**

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">

        </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: wonderful so easy and straight. Can this be implemented using local.xml? sometimes i feel lazy touching theme files ;-)

Comment: Hi folks, It is not working, will you mention the file path how you do that, it would be good if you explain it

Answer (score 0):

```
<customer_logged_in>
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Your Account</label>
        <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" />
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <liParams>
            <id>header-account-link</id>
        </liParams>
        <aParams/>
        <beforeText/>
        <afterText/>                 
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to go along with the accompanying code.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that easily Suppose We need to show only **My-Account** link after sign In,
we have to override the **authorization.phtml** file in custom theme and we can put our logic based on our requirement.
app/design/frontend/Namespace/Custom theme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/ authorization.phtml

After overriding this file we can put our login -

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink $block */

$objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
$dataPostParam = '';
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
}
?>
<?php if($block->isLoggedIn() && $baseurl || $block->isLoggedIn() ) : ?>
 <li class="authorization-link" >
    <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/logout'; ?>">Sign Out</a>
</li>
 <li class="authorization-link custom-top-link-myaccount-mobile" >
   <a href="<?php echo $baseurl .'customer/account/'; ?>">My Account</a>
</li>
<?php else : ?>
 <li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('or')) ?>">
    <a <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLinkAttributes() ?><?= /* @noEscape */ $dataPostParam ?>>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this will help you in Magento2, for managing my account section based own need